# Testing methods using gon with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, gon

I have a function that sends a variable to js with the help of gon.

```
def calc_foo
  # calculate foo
  gon.foo = foo
end
```

I want to test this function i.e make sure that the method return the correct value, using rspec.

```
it "should return bar" do
  foo = @foo_controller.calc_foo
  expect(foo).to eq(bar)
end
```

But, I get the following error message when the test case reaches the line where the variable is sent to gon.

```
Failure/Error: foo = @foo_controller.calc_foo
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `uuid' for nil:NilClass
```

I have checked the value for foo, and it is not Nil, so gon must be Nil. 
I believe the error is that I don't incude gon correctly. This is the rspec-part of my Gemfile

```
#rspec-rails includes RSpec itself in a wrapper to make it play nicely with Rails. 
#Factory_girl replaces Rails’ default fixtures for feeding test data
#to the test suite with much more preferable factories.
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'gon'
end
```

So how can I get rspec to play nicely with gon?
(I have also tried to include gon in my spec-file with no success)

Comment: Run rspec with -b to see where the error is occurring.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I ran rspec -b and I got the following:    


/gems/gon-5.1.2/lib/gon/helpers.rb:49:in `gon_request_uuid'
/gems/ruby-2.1.2@webgraphs/gems/gon-5.1.2/lib    /gon/helpers.rb:32:in `gon'

Answer (score 2):

In the controller specs (where `gon` belongs) you'll need to make an actual request to bypass your problem:

```
RSpec.describe ThingiesController do
  let(:gon) { RequestStore.store[:gon].gon }

  describe 'GET #new' do
    it 'gonifies as expected' do
      get :new, {}, valid_session # <= this one
      expect(gon['key']).to eq :value
    end
  end
end
```

If you'd rather not stick with certain `controller` or `action` for the `gon`-related specs (let's say you have a `gon`-related method in your `ApplicationController`), you could use [Anonymous controller](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) approach:

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationController do
  let(:gon) { RequestStore.store[:gon].gon }

  controller do
    # # Feel free to specify any of the required callbacks,
    # # like
    # skip_authorization_check
    # # (if you use `CanCan`) 
    # # or
    # before_action :required_callback_name

    def index
      render text: :whatever
    end
  end

  describe '#gon_related_method' do
    it 'gonifies as expected' do
      get :index
      expect(gon['key']).to eq :value
    end
  end
end
```

I have lots of `controller` and `request`/`integration` specs and can confirm that `gon` behaves fine there as long as you make actual requests.

However, I still have a problem similar to yours although the case is different (making requests from the `shared_examples` included in the `controller` specs). I've opened the relevant [issue](https://github.com/gazay/gon/issues/198), feel free to join the conversation (for anyone interested).

Answer (score 1):

I test that the controller passes the right stuff to gon in a request spec.

The controller sets an array of objects -- *e.g.*, `gon.map_markers = [...]`

My request spec extracts the JSON via regexp (the `.split()` and `match_array` handle the order-independent-array-ness):

```
....

# match something like
#   gon.map_markers=[{"lat":a,"lng":b},{"lat":c,"lng":d},...];
# and reduce/convert it to
#   ['"lat":a,"lng":b',
#    '"lat":c,"lng":d',
#    ...
#   ]
actual_map_markers = response.body
                     .match('gon.map_markers=\[\{([^\]]*)\}\]')[1]
                     .split('},{')

expect(actual_map_markers).to match_array expected_map_markers
```